# There a Difference between Chinese parsley and cilantro

Tags: herbs

Is there a difference between the two? It looks almost like cilantro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just another name for cilantro AKA coriander, Latin name *coriandrum sativum.*  There is another herb also labelled "Chinese Parsley," but it does NOT resemble cilantro.  This herb is Salt Helioptrope, Latin name *Heliotropium curassavicum*.

**See the picture below for comparison to cilantro:**
[image: Salt Heliotrope]

Comment: And coriander looks like this... http://www.flickr.com/photos/dominiqueb/3826070761/sizes/z/in/photostream/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the picture IS NOT Chinese Parsley.

The weblink below shows the difference between Chinese Parsley and Corriander (cilantro).

Chinese Parsley leaves are more pointy, compared to Cilantro leaves which are rounded.

http://tsgcookingschool.com/2015/04/difference-between-chinese-parsley-coriander/